# Is there a way to get integer object motions in vim?

Tags: vim

I often work on CSS files or other files that require twiddling numbers. I would love the ability to have a key that refers to integers much in the way that `w` refers to a word, or `(` refers to a sentence. For example, in a css file I could navigate to the beginning of a height declaration, and change it's value without having to retype "px" a the end, which is what happens if I use `w`.

Is there such a thing, but I'm missing it in the documentation, or is there a way to add this functionality to my .vimrc?

Bonus points if there were a way to use it like `ci"` where I could be at the begining of the line and use the "change internal" command to jump to AND change the next integer.

More bonus points if I could do simple arithmetic. I would love to be able to issue a concise command that was short for "Add too, internal, integer, 5" and have the next integer on the current line be five grater then it was when I started.

**Edit:**

Some really great proposals everyone, some great ideas that are sure to improve my work. Thanks! Hassek's answer is probably the most likely to end up in my work-flow, but none of the others seem to have (fully) answered my inital question: A motion that works on integers. The proposal tracked down by romainl appears to have that goal<s>, but I can't get it to work reliably</s>.

**For myself (and others perhaps) I will clarify my wants below:**

A key that acts much in the way `w` acts for words, but on integers so that I can simply add it to my mental vim vocabulary and use it seamlessly. This includes the following scenarios. (I will use `d` as my example key):

1. Normal mode `d`: Jump to the next integer
2. Normal mode `cd`: Change to the end of the integer under the cursor (Note that `cw` is a special case that SHOULD change to the NEXT word. `cw` actually acts like `ce`.) I would expect this special case to be implemented with integers as well
3. Visual mode `id`: Select [count] integers.
4. Visual mode `ad`: Select [count] integers. Leading or trailing white space is included.

Am I missing any behavior that `w` has that might be expected for a new motion? Is there even a key available in both normal and visual modes?

Comment: `^A` increments an integer, `^Z` decrements an integer. `f0` will jump to the next `0` on the current line.

Comment: you mistyped `^X` to decrement, not `^Z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this proposal](http://twitter.com/dotvimrc/statuses/184280754686144512). It looks good.

***edit***

Indeed that one is quite nice. This made me think that my habit of doing `/<number><Esc>` was not very efficient so I've added these mappings (and slightly modified the mappings above for consistency) to my `~/.vimrc`. Let's see if they are useful in the long run:

```
nnoremap è  /\v\d+<CR>
nnoremap é  ?\v\d+<CR>
```

At first sight, `èciè132<Esc>` seems to be marginally better than `/2<Esc>{count}s132<Esc>` in terms of keypresses but substantially better if it allows me to skip a. checking the first digit of the value I want to change and b. counting the characters to replace.

Time will tell.

***re-edit***

Here are the function and its mappings:

```
onoremap N  :<c-u>call <SID>NumberTextObject(0)<cr>
xnoremap N  :<c-u>call <SID>NumberTextObject(0)<cr>
onoremap aN :<c-u>call <SID>NumberTextObject(1)<cr>
xnoremap aN :<c-u>call <SID>NumberTextObject(1)<cr>
onoremap iN :<c-u>call <SID>NumberTextObject(1)<cr>
xnoremap iN :<c-u>call <SID>NumberTextObject(1)<cr>

function! s:NumberTextObject(whole)
    normal! v

    while getline('.')[col('.')] =~# '\v[0-9]'
        normal! l
    endwhile

    if a:whole
        normal! o

        while col('.') > 1 && getline('.')[col('.') - 2] =~# '\v[0-9]'
            normal! h
        endwhile
    endif
endfunction
```

With this, I can:

- `vcdy` part of a number from the cursor until its end with `<command>N`. Somehow similarly to `<command>e` or `<command>w`.

  ```
  Here are some random numbers: 24 7635 1000018
                                          ^--->
  ```

  It doesn't work if the cursor is not already on the number and it doesn't go backward.
- `vcdy` a whole number with `<command>iN`.

  ```
  Here are some random numbers: 24 7635 1000018
                                        <-^--->
  ```

  Again, it doesn't work if the cursor is not already on the number.

The whole thing could be improved, sure, but that's a start!

***endedit***

I work a lot with CSS, too.

I use two strategies to change numerical values:

- `{count}<C-a>` and `{count}<C-x>`, as in Hassek's answer, when I know by how much I want to increment/decrement the number. Say I want to turn `20px` into `25px`, a simple `5<C-a>` does the trick without requiring me to move the cursor to the number. This is **extremely cool**.
- `/<number><CR>{count}s<new number>` when the new value is very different from the current value and I feel to lazy to calculate the delta. `/2<CR>2s67<Esc>` would allow me to change `23px` into `67px`. `/2<CR>R67<Esc>` is another way but it's only good if the new value as the same length as the current value. Use `f<number>` if you are on the same line.

Note that you can insert the result of expressions with `<C-r>=137-42<CR>` which I use it very often as well.

Comment: Thanks for tracking down that proposal. That looks very much like what I had initially looked for. Firstly, to get the actual code in a copyable format, I had to use this URL: http://sprunge.us/QTPL

Secondly, I couldn't get it to work reliably. For some-reason it only seems to work every-other time (or there abouts). Maybe something having to do with the native function of `N`?

Comment: @JordanEldredge, please see my edit. It seems to work for me but it's far from being a complete solution.

Comment: @romainl Thank you very much for your clear explanation. I think we were both editing at the same time :) It looks like this is very nearly the answer, in fact the only thing I think it is missing is the expected behavior when outside of an integer.

Comment: @romainl My edit window has expired for my first comment, but I wanted to amend it. The above code DOES seem to be working reliably. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before.

Comment: @romainl you should create a small plugin for this in github, seems worth it.

Comment: Yesterday I've started working on a version that goes forward *and* backward while working over non-numbers like `e` and `b` but I'm not the original author and I have no idea who came up with it first. The same snippet can be found in a couple of places on the net with different usernames associated so I don't know if that would be cool if I took "ownership" of this code. But I agree, a more solid version would be nice. The final code will probably be quite different, though…

Comment: @romainl Did you ever make any progress with a version that goes forward and backward? If not, I may take this up as a project. Let me know.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "progress", maybe "a little bit of poking around". See [here](https://github.com/romainl/my-vim-folder/blob/master/helpers/functions.vim). Go ahead if you have some free time: the rest of the week will be quite busy for me.

Comment: Very useful answer, but links in both answer and comments are now broken or lead wrong.

Answer (score 8):

you can add or substract from integers using this commands:

```
<num>Ctrl-a (to add)
<num>Ctrl-x (to substract)
```

and it will go right to the next number in line and execute the command

Comment: Well, that answers the bonus question and will probably get the job done. This solves my most common case "I need to fudge this box over 5 more pixels". I would still love to know how to change (overwrite) an integer, if it's at all possible. If such a feature does not exists (or show up here soon) you have my answer. Thank you!

Comment: to tell you the truth I haven't found any way to change integers like that, lets give some time to the question to see if someone can apport that info

Answer (score 3):

I found something in the depths of the internetz [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Visually-select-current-match-td4610773.html) and modified it like this

```
nnoremap ,n /\v\d+/b<cr>mah/\v\d+/e<cr>mb`av`b
vnoremap ,n <esc>/\v\d+/b<cr>mah/\v\d+/e<cr>mb`av`b
```

- `\v\d+` searches for a group of digits
- `/b` + `mah` goes to its `b`eginning, sets a mark and goes one character back so we can again
- `\v\d+` search for the same group of digits
- `/e` + `mb` goes to its end and sets another mark and at last
- `` `av`b `` visually selects from the first to the second mark

Comment: damn this reads really as if i was rolling my head on the keyboard

Comment: Who knows? Maybe one could come up with a useful regex that way. Someone with a very pointy/spiky head.

Comment: I am so proud that my head rolled its first regular expression on the keyboard - i will celebrate that, maybe it even gets a new hairdo, so it can roll in style over all the letters.

Comment: Urgh. The hair gel on your keyboard… your IT department won't like your new hairdo.

Comment: my IT department = my home = my castle so the only one that is allowed to complain = me ;). and even if i was in an department - maybe the regexes would it be worth and the management department told everyone to use gel.